# Is there a jQuery or javascript function that lets me have a countdown timer

Tags: javascript, jquery

for a set interval of time that shows the countdown timer on the page. The code below is good unfortunately it doesn't display the time. I am not looking for elaborate lengthy codes but something very simple few lines of code that can get the job done.

```
<script>
  function myFunction() {
    setInterval(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
}
</script>
```

Edit: I don't need a alert. The timer needs to be displayed on the page itself.

Comment: Thanks all. I learnt something new from each of your answers. Heads up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use countdownTimer jquery library for that. I guide you how to do that. First download jquery.countdownTimer.js and jquery.countdownTimer.css files.

html should be as follows.

```
<!-- link java script and css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.countdownTimer.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.countdownTimer.css" />

<div id="countdowntimer"><span id="future_date"><span></div>
```

Javascript should be something like following.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#future_date").countdowntimer({
        dateAndTime : "2015-12-25 00:00:00",
    size : "lg",
        regexpMatchFormat: "([0-9]{1,2}):([0-9]{1,2}):([0-9]{1,2}):([0-9]{1,2})",
            regexpReplaceWith: "$1<sup>days</sup> / $2<sup>hours</sup> / $3<sup>minutes</sup> / $4<sup>seconds</sup>"
    });
});
</script>
```

There are demos on the following url and you can also download all the required files with demo from that. http://harshen.github.io/jquery-countdownTimer/

Comment: Best answer. I wanted to use just for a minute. There is small change to code for minute.  `minutes : 2  size : "lg"` This worked after I removed this line `size : "lg"`.

Answer (score 1):

http://momentjs.com/

You should take a look at that. It is pretty well documented and you have many ways to format your counter

Answer (score 1):

The [getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) method returns the number of milliseconds since midnight of `January 1, 1970`.

```
var startTime = new Date().getTime();

// your code

var endTime = new Date().getTime();
var timeTaken = endTime - startTime;
alert('Execution time: ' + timeTaken);
```

You can use [console.time](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/time) as well.

```
console.time('Function1');

Function1();

console.timeEnd('Function1');
```